# Access denied with composer on CI when installing two projects the same time from a shared cache

Tags: docker, caching, gitlab, composer-php

We are using

```
Composer version 2.0.11 2021-02-24 14:57:23
```

to install packages in a GitLab CI environment on docker boxes.

The aim is to have a global composer across all containers to save bandwith.

The compose cache in the containers is set to `/cache`

Our `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` looks like this:

```
concurrent = 6
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "docker-git-runner-example-dev"
  url = "https://git.example.de/"
  token = "xxxxx"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
    enabled = true
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "ubuntu"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache:/cache", "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/builds:/builds", "/results:/results", "/var/review-test-deploy/:/var/review-test-deploy/" ]
    shm_size = 0
```

Now when the pipeline is triggered, two jobs (`test` and `deploy-review-app`) do a composer install of the same (Magento 2) project in different containers.

One occasionally gets something like this

```
 [ErrorException]                                                                                                           
 copy(/cache/files/aws/aws-sdk-php/3cf3ce74eb752563151499d9305ecba2045b86aa.zip): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Does anybody experience this problem as well? We know there is also GitLab caching which uploads and downloads the cache on the next machine, but we were thinking this is more efficient.

Should we report this as a composer issue and see if some locking mechanism can be improved?

*EDIT*

I tried to make a minium reproducible example without involvement of docker like this:

1. mkdir /tmp/composer/1; cd /tmp/composer 1; composer install (to create the lock file)
2. create any composer.json
3. cd ..
4. cp -R 1 2; cp -R 1 3

Execute this several times:

```
rm */vendor -r ; (cd 1 ; composer2 install; cd .. ) & (cd 2 ; composer2 install; cd .. ) & (cd 3 ; composer2 install; cd .. )
```

The error is not producible.

I have to try it with containers...

*EDIT2* Also not reproducible with the docker version of composer / a shared cache

```
sudo rm -r */vendor ; docker run --rm --volume `pwd`/1:/app   --volume /tmp/composer-cache:/tmp composer:2.0.11 composer -v install & docker run --rm --volume `pwd`/2:/app   --volume /tmp/composer-cache:/tmp composer:2.0.11 composer install & docker run --rm --volume `pwd`/3:/app   --volume /tmp/composer-cache:/tmp composer:2.0.11 composer install & docker run --rm --volume `pwd`/4:/app   --volume /tmp/composer-cache:/tmp composer:2.0.11 composer install
```

Comment: Why not use **one** job to build the application, and run the next tests based on the result of the first one? Also, what makes you think that this is an issue in Composer?

Comment: Good advice. I just want to understand if composer is capable to run multiple installs in parallel with the same cache directory. The issue might otherwise also happen if different applications on the same server install parallel.

Comment: Why not use **distinct** directories for each application? I don't think that Composer was build to support such a case

Comment: Yeah, I think to as well. The idea was to ultimately save traffic

Comment: By using the documented ways of caching (see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/), I've never seen problems like that